# Check if desktop application has been closed abruptly

Tags: c#

In our application there are various documents which users open and if necessary, updates them and while doing this process that particular document is locked for other users. So we have a table where an entry is inserted when an document is opened by any user. For ex his username and docId. Now we have a session, for ex if user has open the document and kept it idle or if user has logged off then the documents are automatically unlocked and they well handled.

But, recently we noticed that there are scenarios where if users opens an document and his system shuts down automatically or if application hangs, user closes it through task manager than in that case the entry is not removed from the table and the document remains lock and it shows lock for other users as well.

Is there any way where we can handle this type of scenarios where if users system closes abruptly and if there’s any document opened on this system should be unlocked and the entry should be removed from the table?

---

I tried doing R&D’s, i came across form close event etc but i am not even sure if what i am searching is relevant to what my expectation is.

Comment: Make the client lock the file every 5 minutes if it's actively working on it, and if it hasn't locked it in 10 minutes, consider it unlocked?

Comment: Bear in mind that computers (and network equipment) can lose power with no warning. You *cannot* rely on any code running on a specific client machine to protect you.

Comment: Maybe you can write a code that can check the windows logs to see if closed decently or not.

Comment: "desktop application" != asp.net

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: To implement this, we have to give an pop up or somethIng to the client after every 5 mins to keep it unlocked because no client will do it upfront. And by giving that option to client, suppose 1st time i.e. after 5 mins  he missed to unlock and soon after that his system shuts down or application hangs than again we’ll run into the same problem right?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: That’s true but i was truly looking for some workaround here. As this is affecting our clients tremendously.

Comment: @KlausGütter: Sorry I didn’t get it, i mean off course i do get, desktop application is not equal to asp.net but not the actual meaning behind it.

Comment: @firatt_ : what if when application hangs and client closes it through task manager but not actual system shutting down?

Comment: You tagged your question "asp.net", that's what I was commenting on.

Comment: One imperfect solution is to have a launcher app which monitors the main app to see if it has died and takes the appropriate response if so.

Comment: I'm quite sure @JoachimIsaksson meant that your application would automatically re-lock the file every 5 minutes. And if that it's gone 10 minutes, you can assume something bad has happened and release the lock.

Comment: Not a solution, but may reduce impact is to unlock all docs for user at start-up. If system crashes, often user will restart application, so fixes issue that way.  Of course, docs remain locked until user restarts application. Or in your DB, create a users table & each user periodically updates a timestamp there. A central task can then monitor that and release any users that don't appear active (e.g. not posted time in last 10 mins)

Comment: There is no "wonderful solution" for such situation. But there are certainly steps you can take to minimize the impact. For example, a service can run and monitor locks. If the lock corresponds to an idling user (no activity for certain duration), service unlocks the record.

Comment: Are you using WinForms? Have you looked at FormClosing event? That could help a bit. But as is said before, I would set a timer on how long a lock is taken and have the app automatically refresh the timestamp on that lock while it's running

Answer (score 0):

> case the entry is not removed from the table and the document remains lock and it shows lock for other users as well.

Either focus on the system that keeps the document "locked" and "unlock" it after a certain period of inactivity.

Or have the app keep a log of activity, so that when it dies, that it resumes the session with the host.

Regardless, you should be handling normal shutdown events, such as window close, and removing any locks on the document.